# Validating data entry against a repository

Tags: java, validation

I'm attempting to create a 'demo' payment service where you enter card information and it validates to a database to confirm whether the info you enter is valid. At the minute its pretty basic as the database is just an excel spreadsheet but the aim is to expand once the basic validation is complete.
I'm still very new to programming and struggling to work out how when you input the card number, cvv2 number and a postcode how you would check the inputs against the information held in the database? And how an error would be populated if this information was incorrect. Here is the code for my repository class so far :

```
public class DataRepository {

   private List<DataRecord> allData = new ArrayList<>();

   public DataRepository(String excelFilePath) {

     FileInputStream inputStream;
     try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row nextRow = iterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    break;
                }
                System.out.print(" - ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public List<DataRecord> getAllData() {
    return allData;
  }

  public void setAllData(List<DataRecord> allData) {
    this.allData = allData;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept is to create interface called like `ExternalServices` with methods like `isCardCorrect`, which takes as input parameters all relevant information (in your case card number, cvv2 number and a postcode) and returns for example true/false.

In your application you are using just this interface and call methods from it.

Then you are able to create several classes which implements this interface, like `ExcelService implements ExternalServices` and `DatabaseService implements ExternalServices`.

Based on which class you create, every single call is then send to excel or database.

---

For error handling, you have Exceptions and try-catch statements.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply, I have a 'PayService' class which has this public Boolean isCardNumberValid() {
  return Boolean.TRUE;
 }                                                                                                            At the risk of sounding stupid, I'm struggling to understand how they can share this information now. What would I need in order to send this information to the excel or database?

Comment: Yes, it seems correct. Just remember that concept. Have PayService as interface and PayServiceImpl as class you are using (or something similar). Or maybe I am not sure what are you asking for really.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I need to try and grasp the process a little more before moving further in if I'm honest